# a sharing violation occurred while accessing with paint

Tags: c#, wpf, paint

i have a image. and i open it in image viewer that i created. now i want to edit this image. so i open this image in paint and when i click on save button after change it give me. some error of a sharing violation occurred while accessing.

i remove the file name from image viewer before open image in paint.

here is my code..

```
private void btnEditImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (File.Exists(Helper.DefaultPath + listImages[count].Path))
            {
                SetNullImage();
                string editPath = Helper.DefaultPath + listImages[count].Path;
                if (File.Exists(editPath))
                {
                    Process my = new Process();
                    my.StartInfo.FileName = "mspaint.exe";
                    my.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + editPath + "\"";
                    my.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    my.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                    my.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);
                    my.Start();
                }
            }
        }
        private void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                SetImage();
            }));
        }
```

See Images

Open In Image viewer:
[image: Open In Image viewer]

thanks...

Error when make changes in image and click on save:
[image: Error when make changes in image and click on save]

Comment: have you tried to save a copy of the file instead using the image you have in use? For me it sounds like paint can not save your file because it's either write protected or the file is still in use (maybe a stream of your progamm?)

Comment: would you give any other suggestion. i have to work on the same file. or if you have any example then pls share it also.

Comment: I've just made an educated guess. You don't provide a [mcve] either. Please also see [ask]. Anyway: you get this error because the file is in use or you have no rights to write.

Answer (score 0):

While you call `SetImage()` Method, make sure that you are using `Image.FromFile()` Method. If you using That, Use Bellow code instead of that

```
  private Bitmap SetImage(){
      pictureBox1.Image = GetImageFromPath(ImagePath)
  }

  private Bitmap GetImageFromPath(string Path)
  {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(Path))
        {
            using (Bitmap tmpBitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(streamReader.BaseStream))
            {
                return tmpBitmap;
            }
        }
   }
```